# SharePoint to show 'Working days left' and blank if other column is marked 'Complete'

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I've been looking on this page and others can't seem to get exactly what I'm looking for, not sure if it is possible but I will ask.

One column shows 'Delivery Date' so I've used the following to show how many days under/over compared to today:

```
=[Delivery Due]-TODAY()&" days"
```

This shows all days but I need to show it in business days.

Some entries are now complete so the counter is still rising, so I want it to look at another column marked 'Delivery Status' and if this is marked 'Complete' to just show a blank or other test.

Apologies, absolute novice to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula for your calculated column in SharePoint list:

```
=IF([Delivery Status]="Complete","",[Delivery Due]-TODAY()&" days")
```

This should show the blank result when "Delivery Status" column is marked as "Complete".

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.